# Is there a way to provide two sets of rest parameters in one function definition?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

I am trying to use a function that takes in an undetermined number of elements and classes. The number of elements will always match the number of classes. I know I can use rest parameters to accept an unknown number of arguments, but is it even possible to do that for two sets?

This is what I am thinking ⬇️:

```
const toggleClass = (axn, ...elements, ...classname) => {
    elements[0].classList[axn](classname[0])
    elements[1].classList[axn](classname[1])
}

heroBtn.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => toggleClass('add', arrowEl, btnTextEl, 'arrow-hover', 'btn-text-hover'))
heroBtn.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => toggleClass('remove', arrowEl, btnTextEl, 'arrow-hover', 'btn-text-hover'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - if that were possible, it would be unclear to the interpreter which argument goes into which rest parameter. Eg with

```
fn = (...args1, ...args1) => {
```

and

```
fn('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

How could the interpreter decide which elements to put in which array?

You'll have to separate out the elements yourself.

For what you're doing, I'd prefer to pass arrays:

```
toggleClass(
  'add',
  [arrowEl, btnTextE1],
  ['arrow-hover', 'btn-text-hover']
);
```

Then iterate over them.